# C# надежное логирование

Tags: c#

Как организовать надежную запись при логировании?
Иногда возникает ошибка:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '..\Log\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Запись в файл происходит каждую секунду. Вот мой метод:

```
private static void WriteInFile(string fullpath, string message)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullpath, true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + message);
    }
}
```

**PS Не нужно предлагать готовые библиотеки для логирования.**

Comment: Вы небось пишете в файл одновременно из разных потоков?

Comment: @VladD нет, 1 поток.

Comment: Тогда с вас воспроизводящий пример. Для однопоточного случая код выглядит правильно.

Comment: @VladD вангую варианты: несколько процессов или файл открыт по F3 в FAR Manager

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вроде FAR, умеет открывать не блокируя, а вот Notepad стандартный - нет

Comment: @Grundy все наоборот. Notepad после чтения файла закрывает его, а вот FAR держит открытым

Comment: @PavelMayorov, стандартный блокнот закрывает файл после чтения???

Comment: @creamsun посмотрите через `Procmon.exe ` кто лочит файлы

Comment: @Grundy а зачем его открытым-то держать?

Comment: и вообще порекомендовал бы вам юзать какой нибудь `CacheFileEventLogger`, если вы очень часто пишете в лог. скажем собрали 10 сообщений, потом записали в файл и т.д.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator э... а вы язык не перепутали?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, класс из другого "мира", но я хотел передать идею реализации

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Спасибо, за идею!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), она позволяет включать и отключать защиту файла при записи, и держать ли файл "открытым", очень удобная и гибкая библиотека

```
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
...
Log.Info("Log");
Log.Error("Log");
Log.Debug("Log");
```

Также позволяет записывать Info, Error, Debug и т.д. в разные файлы, есть возможность даже писать в БД

Comment: Спасибо, но я не ищу готовую библиотеку, а ищу решение проблемы.

Comment: @creamsun готовая библиотека  - это и есть решение проблемы

Comment: @PavelMayorov из-за специфики работы, я не могу использовать готовые библиотеки.

Comment: @creamsun что за "специфика работы"?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Nlog, а так у вас ошибка того, что в этот файл что-то уже пишут.  [Примеры использования](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial).

Comment: без using плохо жить с потоками

Comment: Обычно я такого не говорю - но сейчас скажу. *Автор, убейся об стену!* Шесть редакций ответа - а он все еще не содержит правильного решения вопроса...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Что именно не так? _Сам убейся!_

Comment: воу воу воу, полегче ребята.

Comment: @YuryBakharev ваш код ничем не отличается от кода автора, кроме блокировки. Но у него всего 1 поток - так что блокировка ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, как вы считаете так нормально? Только если он занят ничего туда не запишется(

Comment: @YuryBakharev теперь у вас еще и гонка

Comment: @PavelMayorov вообщем уже не актуально. удаляю "гонку"

Answer (score 0):

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Thread-free read
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static byte[] ConcurentReadFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Read))
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs)) return br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread-free write
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath"></param>
    /// <param name="fileBytes"></param>
    private static void ConcurentWriteFile(string filePath, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Read))
        using (var br = new BinaryWriter(fs)) br.Write(fileBytes);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Дополню

```
private static Object obj = new Object();
private static void Foo(string fullpath, string message)
{        
  lock(obj)
  {
    while (true)
      try{
        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fullpath, true)) 
        {      
          sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + message);     
          sw.Close();
        }
        break;
      }      
      catch{ }
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы два раза закрываете файл? Зачем блокировка в однопоточном приложении? Вы уверены, что пропадающие логи - это нормально?

Comment: Прочитав комментарии к вопросу я так понял, проблема что этот файл дергает вообще другое приложение.

Comment: блокировку можно и убрать, однако лучше подстраховаться на предмет многопоточности. По поводу пустого catch, что не так?

Comment: @YuryBakharev автору нужно "надёжное логирование". Если он понимает под этим термином "обязательно записать в файл", то получите и распишетесь. Или зависни до удачного стечения обстоятельств. А так "надёжного" логирования не существует. А то что кто то "ныряет" в файл и не закрывает его это факт.